# How can I optimize this element by element vector addition and multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to optimize the inner loop of my python code. I've been reading about map, and reduce, but struggle to apply these concepts to the following code, since it also contains a multiplication. My data structure looks like this

```
f.m: [NDArray[float]] 
f.l: [NDArray[float]]
f.h: [NDArray[float]]
```

I have several of these in a list and I would like to calculate the sum for each array element (i.e., m, l, h) in the list. Right now, I use a loop to iterate through the list of arrays. This scenario can be done with map etc. However, each array also carries a sign (+1. vs -1). Is there a way to optimize this and keeping the sign separate?

```
f1 = type('test', (object, ), {})()
f2 = type('test', (object, ), {})()

f1.n = "f1"
f1.m = f1.l = [1, 2]

f2.n = "f2"
f2.m = f2.l = [2, 4]

flux_list = [f1, f2]
dirs = {"f1": -1, "f2": 1}

new = [0, 0]
i = 0  # set in outer loop

for f in flux_list:
    direction = dirs[f.n]
    new[0] +=  f.m[i] * direction
    new[1] +=  f.l[i] * direction

print(new)
```

Comment: if `f` is a `list` of `ndarray`, what is `f.n`, `f.m`, `f.l`, and `f.h`? Can you add more detail and context to your [mre]?

Comment: good point. edited accordingy

Comment: `map`, `reduce` etc can make writing Python code for lists and dicts prettier, but they don't change speed much.  There's not list equivalent to the `numpy` whole-array compiled methods.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the above loop is to create the data structure outside of the object instances, and then use numpy.view() to create individual views on the data.

unlike np.r_, np.view() does not create a new copy of the data, so anything we do to the data is visible in all other views (similar to shared memory).

I.e., we can create a view where f1.m and f2.m appear to be adjacent to each other, and we can use np.sum on the view rather than a loop over each f1 to fn. While this involves a small overhead in creating the data structure, all of this can be done before we start iterating over the data.
Last but not least, the multiplication step can be moved outside the loop by a suitable grouping of f.m (I,.e.collect all f.m with positive sign into one group, and do the same for those with q negative sign).

The code below illustrates the principle:

```
import numpy as np

# create the data structure first
rand = np.random.RandomState(42)
A = rand.randint(10,size=25).reshape(5,5)
row = np.arange(5)

# create some empty object instances
f1 = type('test', (object, ), {})()
f2 = type('test', (object, ), {})()

# Assign views into A to each object
f1.m = A.view()[row[:, np.newaxis], 0]
f1.l = A.view()[row[:, np.newaxis], 3]

f2.m = A.view()[row[:, np.newaxis], 1]
f2.l = A.view()[row[:, np.newaxis], 2]

# Create view in such a way that we can directly sum the data
# in this case we want to add f1.m and f2.m
col = np.array([0,1])
C=A.view()[row[:, np.newaxis], col]

# do the sum over the view which will then also be
# reflected in A
np.sum(C,axis=1)
```